# allow read access to secretsmanagr in cdk pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

```
    // SourceAction
    const sourceAction = new BitBucketSourceAction({
        actionName: 'BitbucketSource',
        owner: 'ownername',
        repo: repoName,
        output: sourceOutputArtifact,
        connectionArn: SecretValue.secretsManager('BBCloudConnection').toString(),
    })
```

This is what the source action looks like. I need it to be able to access connectionArn from SecretValue. It fails due to lack of permissions at the moment. Where should the resource permission be added?
I am using the pipeline from AWS code example here at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-simple-cicd

Action in deploymentPolicy looks as follows:

```
        Action:
            - 'cloudformation:*'
            - 'iam:*'
            - 'lambda:*'
            - 'ecs:*'
            - 'ecr:*'
            - 'logs:*'
            - 'ec2:*'
            - 'ssm:*'
            - 'secretsmanager:*'
```

i.e have added 'secretsmanager:*' at the bottom

As of now, I get the following error if I use secretsManager:

`17/49 | 2:14:10 a.m. | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Policy            | backend--854-pipeline-backend-setup-pipeline/Source/BitbucketSource/CodePipelineActionRole/DefaultPolicy (backendVLNCC854pipelinebackendsetuppipelineSourceBitbucketSourceCodePipelineActionRoleDefaultPolicy41F7C61D) Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 62b6fb1c-77b0-432c-b907-2e409ff7c538; Proxy: null)`

The secret  was created manually on console and has the following resource permissions:

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/deployment-role"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: The link to GH does not work. Can you provide full policy you are using now.

Comment: @Marcin Updated the link